# Ubuntu keyboard mapping

Tags: ubuntu

In Ubuntu 16.04, how do I discover which keyboard button is assigned to backslash?

I have used the -pke option in xmodmap to list the keyboard layout. The result lists 255 keycodes. Which keycode corresponds to backslash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the little tool `xev`.

It's an event tester and will start open a little white window where it detects mouse and keyboard events. It will print the output to the console.

E.g. a backslash gives me the following output:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x4a9, subw 0x0, time 1190007, (62,493), root:(1747,545),
    state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x4a9, subw 0x0, time 1190519, (62,493), root:(1747,545),
    state 0x90, keycode 20 (keysym 0x5c, backslash), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5c) "\"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5c) "\"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x4a9, subw 0x0, time 1190671, (62,493), root:(1747,545),
    state 0x90, keycode 20 (keysym 0x5c, backslash), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5c) "\"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
    root 0x4a9, subw 0x0, time 1190815, (62,493), root:(1747,545),
    state 0x90, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The first event is the modifier key I have to press on my keyboard. The second is the actual key where the backslash is. Then follow the two release events.

Answer (score 0):

When executed in my Ubuntu 14.04 I found it as follows (keycode 51):

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep -i slash
keycode  16 = 7 slash 7 ampersand braceleft seveneighths
keycode  20 = apostrophe question minus underscore backslash questiondown
keycode  28 = t T t T tslash Tslash
keycode  32 = o O o O oslash Oslash
keycode  49 = masculine ordfeminine grave asciitilde backslash backslash
keycode  51 = ccedilla Ccedilla backslash bar braceright dead_breve
keycode  61 = minus underscore slash question dead_belowdot dead_abovedot
```